# ReactJS - What Alternatives are there to ContextType?

Tags: reactjs

In keeping with the one purpose only principle of components, I have a deeply layered component, that **many depths below has a open modal button**.

[image]

When first completing the entire page, I foolishly realized that having the function to open the modal at a very deep level child, caused the modal window to open within that child's parameters and not the window as a whole.

When trying to overcome this, I found myself, too liberally **passing down prop functions to sub components that had no need for that prop save to be passed down even further**. I can see how this would be a nightmare down the road.

As a last resort I opted for context type:

**Main Page Component:**

```
export default class MainPage extends Component {
     ......

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      openModal: (arg) => this.openModal(arg)
      }
  }

  openModal(content) {
    if (content !== undefined) {
      const open = content.modalOpen
      this.setState({modalOpen: open});
    }
}

render() {
   .....
  return(
      { modalOpen ?
        <Modal>
           ....
        </Modal>
       : '' }
    )   
  }
}
```

**Many generations down child component:**

```
export default Child extends Component {

    ....

  static contextTypes = {
    openModal: PropTypes.func
  };

  render() {
      .....
      <img src="/images/shared/zoom_in.png"
           onClick={ this.context.openModal.bind(this, { modalOpen: true }) }
         ....
      />
      .....
 }
  ...
```

}

One reads often where contextType is discouraged and may be done away with in the future, but in this scenario, I cannot see a cleaner, more efficient approach.

Under the scenario I discussed, am I following a prudent approach or might there be a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would have my child view dispatch an event that can be handled on in the root component.

Webpack and Browserify both have convenient ways to use a nodejs like event emitter in the browser. This is also what most flux implementations use for their dispatcher.

You could export a singleton instance of an event emitter that you require in both child and parent. ie..

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'events'
exports default new EventEmitter()
```

then from your child component you can

```
import emitter from './youemitter'
....
  openModal() {
    emitter.dispatchEvent(OPEN_MODAL, props)
  }
```

and in your parent you can just

```
import emitter from './youremitter'
....
  componentDidMount() {

    emitter.addEventListener(OPEN_MODAL, this.openYourModal)
```

In the same way you can listen to events from your child views to update your data model or flux store or what you may have and rerender.

Comment: Great, I will look into that.

Comment: browserify and webpack is nodejs. But you could of course also simply dispatch dom events. Or build your own event emitter. Good thing about using the node.js event-emitter is that the code will be environment agnostic